# Unblocking AngularJS UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app. My app allows the user to enter a number and press execute. When the execute button is pressed, I am dynamically building an array for processing. While the array is being built, the UI seems to lock. I have the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="numToExecute"></input>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="execute()">Execute</button>

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" ng-if="buildingArray === true">
  <strong>Building array</strong><br />
</div>

$scope.preloadedItems = loadArray();
$scope.executeTests = function() {
  $scope.buildingArray = true;

  var i = 0;
  angular.forEach($scope.preloadedItems, function(item) {
    if (i < numToExecute) {
      $scope.myArray.push({ id: item.id });      
    }
    i = i + 1;
  });

  $scope.buildingArray = false;
  $scope.processArray();
};
```

The box the says "Building array" never appears. Its like the ui locks until the angular.forEach statement is done. the `preloadedItems` array has thousands of entries in it. That's why I want to show the "Building array" box.

Is there a way to unblock the UI? Or, at least show the building array box?

Thanks!

Comment: where is numToExecute declared?

Comment: also, you need to defer your method and wait until the method is complete before setting buildingArray back to false --- research the 'promise'

Comment: [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers), but unless I'm missing something, why not splice?

Comment: the code demonstrates a general misunderstanding of how the browser works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the angular.forEach in $timeout

```
$timeout(function(){
  angular.forEach($scope.preloadedItems, function(item) {
    if (i < numToExecute) {
      $scope.myArray.push({ id: item.id });      
    }
    i = i + 1;
  });
},0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you perform high amount of calculations or create really big data, you should remember that all page works in one thread. You can split your processing code into pieces so UI will be refreshed, it will be a bit slow, but will work!

There is a function to delay execution - `setTimeout`. For example, you can run a cycle in your code and each iteration run in `setTimeout`.